# Range of dates in MongoDB's document

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating a collection with describes of excursions. Every document in collection describes one excursion. How can I define a range of avelable dates for concrete excursion? How to do it better?

Comment: Without code and a sample collection document this question cannot be answered. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying something like this:
db.excursion.insertOne(
... {name:"My city",type:"walk",max_amount:6,price:154}
... )
How can I add a range of avelable dates?

Comment: Maybe you mean adding a `start_date` and an `end_date` and then querying for a date within that range? Or do you need an array of date pairs with a start and end for each?

Comment: @IanMercer, thanks for your answer. I will attempt to explain what I want.
I have a collection with a describes of excursions, I'm creating documents for the collection as I written above. Now I need somehow to indicating a list of accessible dates for every excursions. 
Then users will selecting amoung these excursions and selected excursions must be mark as reserved.
But I'm not confident how to do it right. Maybe create a particular collection of dates, for instance with 2018-04-19 to 2100-01-01 and then use indexes that to mark those dates wich will be reserved?

Comment: update the question rather than commenting on it if you can make it clearer. Also suggest you use common database terms: what are the entities, what properties do they have, what are the relationships between them, are they 1:1, 1:n or n:m? etc. and maybe a diagram. And/or try something, show what you did and then ask for help fixing it.